# Hover dropdown menu Bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap5

Как сделать такое dropdown menu с использованием Bootstrap 5?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это один из самых простых, всё зависит от ваших целей.
Если просто открытие выпадающего меню, то это простой вариант

```
.dropdown:hover.dropdown-menu {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, что можно сделать примерно так.
Просто можем взять готовую плашку и дальше ее поменять.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <p class="">И тут пишем наше меню, стилизуем уже сами</p>
</div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```